# tensoring with line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is known that $\mathrm{Ext}^i(\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})\simeq \mathrm{Ext}^i(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{L}^{\vee}\otimes\mathcal{G})$. Does this hold for complexes in the derived category i.e. do we have isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{L}\otimes^L \mathcal{F}^{\bullet},\mathcal{G}^{\bullet}[k])\simeq\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{F}^{\bullet},\mathcal{L}^{\vee}\otimes^L\mathcal{G}^{\bullet}[k])$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since $L$ is dual to $L^*$ in the category of coherent sheaves, via some unit and counit homomorphisms, the same is true for them as objects of the derived category, via the same unit and counit, but now concentrated in degree 0.

Comment: You mean $\mathcal{L}$ has to be concentrated in degree 0 viewed as a complex